# Updating a user model in Django when they fill out a form on a different model

Tags: python, django

I am struggling to work out how to achieve something and would appreciate someone suggesting the correct Django way to do it.

I have a custom user model which is fairly basic but includes a BooleanField which says whether they have filled out a voluntary equality and diversity form. There is a very basic model which holds the equality and diversity form data without any reference to the users which filled out each response. What I want is this, when a user fills out a valid equality and diversity form it puts True in the user model box to say they have filled out the form.

I would be massively appreciative if anyone knows the correct way to do this as I am tying myself up in knots and have got myself quite confused.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

**users/models.py**

```py
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    # Has the user completed the EDI form?
    edi = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile', args=[str(self.username)])
```

**equality_diversity/models.py**

```py
class EqualityDiversity(models.Model):
    age = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=AGE_CHOICES)
    ethnicity = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    ... (etc)
```

**equality_diversity/views.py**

```py
class EqualityDiversityView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = EqualityDiversity
    template_name = 'equality_diversity.html'
    form_class = EqualityDiversityForm
    login_url = 'login'

    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: It is always the way that when I actually get around to asking the question I kinda work out the answer! I think my mistake here is being an idiot and putting it in a different app.

Comment: Will do, when I have! I am still struggling but getting closer.

Comment: I thought you comment means you figured it out, I'll see what I can do

Comment: Thanks man! So I have moved the equality form into the users app as a separate class, but nothing more at this stage. My brain is still struggling to work out the logic of what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class EqualityDiversityView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = EqualityDiversity
    template_name = 'equality_diversity.html'
    form_class = EqualityDiversityForm
    login_url = 'login'

    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # this is a view, You have self.request
        self.request.user.edi = True
        # apply changes to db
        self.request.user.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)  # redirects to success_url
```

or better

```
class EqualityDiversityView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = EqualityDiversity
    template_name = 'equality_diversity.html'
    form_class = EqualityDiversityForm
    login_url = 'login'

    success_url = '/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # form.instance is an instance of the model that the form defines in META
        form.instance.edi = True
        # apply changes to db
        form.instance.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)  # redirects to success_url
```

Comment: Take this as a habit, In every function you override, Print the arguments to see what does they have, Also use PyCharm as it helps a lot while learning